# Pandas data frame: Getting tuples groups separated by 'NaN' in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new so please help me. Let's say I have a df as follows

```
     words
0    peter
1    is
2    a
3    good
4    man
5    NaN
6    i
7    am 
8    hungry
9    NaN
```

I want a list of tuples grouped together before the NaN values. The output should be like this.

```
[['peter','is','a','good','man'],['i','am','hungry']]
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
g = df.words.isna()
df[~g].groupby(g.cumsum()).words.apply(list).tolist()                                                              
# [['peter', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'man'], ['i', 'am', 'hungry']]
```

Answer (score 1):

No worries. This is a simple way to do it:

```
lst = [list(df.words)[:5], list(df.words)[6:9]]

lst

>>>[['peter', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'man'], ['i', 'am', 'hungry']]
```

P.S. Those aren't actually tuples, they're lists within a list.

Comment: I am assuming your data frame is called 'df'.

Comment: It's often helpful to put your assumptions, or make some form of declaration of the variables/items you're referring to directly in the answer you provide. Any additional context and definition will help future readers.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have a very large list and I wanted to achieve this using a function or loop. Can you please show how to do this if the list is very large?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[(df.words.fillna(0) != 0) == True] 
a = df.groupby(df.index - np.arange(df.shape[0])).words.apply(list).to_list()
```

output:

```
 [['peter', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'man'], 
['i', 'am', 'hungry']]
```

For the second ask in the comments, try this:

```
thelist = []
newlist = []
for x,y in df.words.fillna(0).iteritems():
    if y == 0:
       thelist.append(newlist)
       newlist = []
    else:
       newlist.append(y)   
thelist = [x for x in thelist if x != []]
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have a very large list and I wanted to achieve this using a function or loop. Can you please show how to do this if the list is very large?

Comment: @inzi i added another update, lmk if this works for you

Comment: Nice! Great question btw.